# JButton does not appear until moused over

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, repaint

When i run my program everything works as planned except that the button i have to change the cards on the screen does not appear until it is moused over. Im assuming this is because whatever container that is holding the images is over it but i dont know how to move it into the background or even what kind of container i can use to add images to.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class oneplayer extends JFrame {
    BufferedImage  image1, image2, image3, image4;
    Random gen = new Random();
    public void redo() {
        int p1, p2, p3, p4;
        p1 = gen.nextInt(13) + 1;
        p2 = gen.nextInt(13) + 14;
        p3 = gen.nextInt(13) + 27;
        p4 = gen.nextInt(13) + 40;
         try {
         File input1 = new File("C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/eclipse/workspace/inClass/src/" + p1 + ".png");
         File input2 = new File("C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/eclipse/workspace/inClass/src/" + p2 + ".png");
         File input3 = new File("C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/eclipse/workspace/inClass/src/" + p3 + ".png");
         File input4 = new File("C:/Users/Mike/Desktop/eclipse/workspace/inClass/src/" + p4 + ".png");
         image1 = ImageIO.read(input1);
         image2 = ImageIO.read(input2);
         image3 = ImageIO.read(input3);
         image4 = ImageIO.read(input4);
     } catch (IOException ie) {
         System.out.println("Error:"+ie.getMessage());
     }
     repaint();
}

public oneplayer() {
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JButton refresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    refresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            redo();
        }
    });
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    buttonPanel.add(refresh, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    redo();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
     g.drawImage(image1, 20, 55, null);
     g.drawImage(image2, 96, 55, null);
     g.drawImage(image3, 172, 55, null);
     g.drawImage(image4, 248, 55, null);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    oneplayer frame = new oneplayer();
    frame.setTitle("Random Cards");
    frame.setSize(350, 200);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't override `paint()` method. Instead override `paintComponent()` of main container.

Call `super.paintComponent(g)`

Don't extend `JFrame` but e.g. `JPanel`, add all you content to the panel and set the panel as a content pane of usual `JFrame` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call `super.paint(g)` inside your `paint(Graphics)` function to ensure that the Swing components inside the frame are properly displayed.

Comment: While technically correct, it is preferred that custom painting be performed on a child container, like JPanel, using its paintComponent method instead

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this with your sample, but I think you need to call the parent class's paint when overriding paint on your Frame in order for the Frame's components to show up. Like so:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
     super.paint(g);
     g.drawImage(image1, 20, 55, null);
     g.drawImage(image2, 96, 55, null);
     g.drawImage(image3, 172, 55, null);
     g.drawImage(image4, 248, 55, null);
}
```

Comment: While technically correct, it is preferred that custom painting be performed on a child container, like JPanel, using its paintComponent method instead